# How do we get the same stored procedure code to call a different database server depending upon the calling environment?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

We have environments for Dev, Uat, and Live. We have a different version of the same stored procedure for each environment. For each environment, a stored procedure is run from a database catalog of the same name "CMS". In each case, the sql that is called differs only on the server name. For example, the code on UAT looks like this (simplified):

```
  INSERT INTO UAT.ABC.[dbo].NOTE (ID, [TEXT])
    VALUES (2, 'Just a note')
```

The code on Live looks like this (simplified):

```
  INSERT INTO Live.ABC.[dbo].NOTE (ID, [TEXT])
    VALUES (2, 'Just a note')
```

We would like to just write the stored procedure once and be able to deploy that same stored procedure so that it points to the right server when, say, performing the insert statement in our example. We wish to avoid using dynamic sql. Is there a way to pass down a parameter into the stored procedure to tell it which server to use? Can this be achieved using sqlcmd with scripting variables, if so then how? Is there an easy way of doing this without dynamic sql or scripting variables?

**EDIT**

Six separate instances of SQL Server 2014 - 3 for each environment for the calling code and 3 for each environment for the code being called.

Comment: Are UAT, Dev, and Live all separate SQL Server instances?

Comment: Six separate instances of SQL Server 2014 - 3 for each environment for the calling code and 3 for each environment for the code being called.

Comment: ok, and are UAT, Dev, and Live in this case linked servers?

Comment: Yes, each server can see all other servers as linked servers, except production cannot see anything other than itself.

Comment: Do the calls ever cross environments? Would Dev use the linked server to UAT?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there are 3 copies of the DB with "identical" code, or rather to code should be identical. Remove the hardcoded DB reference, and the stored procedure will run in the context of the DB in which it lives.
You are making life hard for yourself by hardcoding the db reference.

And you answer your own question. If you ahve to do this, then you must use dynamic SQL.

Comment: The calling code does not exist on the same server as the code that it calls. Six separate instances of SQL Server 2014 - 3 for each environment for the calling code and 3 for each environment for the code being called.

Comment: then you have no choice but to use dynamic sql

Comment: just curious why you can't keep a stored procedure to insert data on the server you are actually inserting into. It makes maintenance and life alot easier.

Comment: maybe use views? to promote to the different environment, modify the view to point to the different environment, then the stored procedure can just reference the view, and not have to change. Not sure if this will work in your particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the Linked Server name the same in all instances, and just change the *definition* of where the linked server points to go to the correct instance.

So use something like:

```
 INSERT INTO MyAppLinkedServer.ABC.[dbo].NOTE (ID, [TEXT])
    VALUES (2, 'Just a note')
```

In UAT, MyAppLinkedServer will point to UAT SQL server.
In Dev, MyAppLinkedServer will point to DEV SQL server.

Here is an example of how to setup the linked server:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver  @server = N'MyAppLinkedServer', @srvproduct=N'MyAppLinkedServer', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'ActualServerNameGoesHere', @catalog=N'ABC'
```

Comment: That would help if it didn't break everything that uses current names for linked servers.

Comment: Everything that uses current names for linked servers breaks when you move between dev/uat/live right now anyway, right?

Comment: For the "everything that users current names for linked server", Do you have situations where your Dev environment would use the UAT or Live linked server? and the same for the other instances?  If it is the same for those existing queries, then in your Dev environment, setup yous DEV/UAT/LIVE linked servers to *all* point to the Dev SQL Server (and same for UAT/Live environments).  That way it doesn't matter which you use.  It's not pretty but that would fix the issue for the legacy queries that are using hard coded linked server names.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer was not to use any linked servers but to create any entry the host file for each environment, where the entry would have a different IP mapping for each environment.